# Spring Boot: Не находит страницу

Tags: java, spring, сервер, spring-boot, controller

Пытаюсь запустить приложение, но не находит страницу. Выдает ошибку 404. Файл index находится в папке templates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>fgfg</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
    
  
        registry.addResourceHandler("/jquery/**") //
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.3.1-1/");

     
        registry.addResourceHandler("/popper/**") //
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/popper.js/1.14.1/umd/");

     
        registry.addResourceHandler("/bootstrap/**") //
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.1.1/");
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String test(Model model) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением: ((No more passes unfortunately, you'll likely be confused if you haven't read at least series three first.))

в build.gradle файл